# Превью картинок при вставке в поле ввода

Tags: jquery, изображения, javascript

Хочется сделать автоматическую загрузку картинок (превью) при вставке в поле ввода, как это реализовано в соцсетях. Есть ли готовые js библиотеки для таких целей? Хотелось бы, чтобы всё работало максимально кроссбраузерно. Или подскажите, от чего отталкиваться при разработке. Думал сделать это с использованием FileReader(), т.е. считывать картинки из поля ввода, потом обрабатывать и выводить в превью, но оно ведь не работает в сафари 5 и т.д.

**Обновление**

Ну, drag&drop тоже бы хотелось, но для начала просто преобразовать вставленный урл картинки в миниатюру с возможностью удалить.
Например, пользователь вводит:

> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/upfiles/logo.png

ставит пробел, под textarea появляется миниатюра (наверняка видели такой функционал в соцсетях).

Comment: @Floyat, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

То есть возможность drag&drop картинки в поле ввода?

**Обновление**

Ну так надо отследить событие, например keyup, проверять на наличие ссылки, например /http:/.test(), если такое находит, пишем `$("#textarea").after('<img src="ссылка">');`

Answer (score 1):

Ну смотрите, сценарий такой:

1. Пользователь постит ссылку (обновляет поле)
2. Обработчик видит, что поле обновлено, и пытается найти в нем новые ссылки на изображения

   1. Вычленяет вообще все ссылки
   2. Находит среди них новые
3. Добавляет под полем теги `<img/>` для новых изображений.

Последний пункт на самом деле несколько сложнее - по ссылке может оказаться что угодно, и сначала надо убедиться, что по ссылке именно изображение. Скорее всего, можно попробовать загрузить адрес, как обычное изображение и по состоянию элемента определить, всё ли ок, и только после этого показать.

Comment: Вот последнее больше всего волнует. Как проверить средствами JS-jquery, что ссылка - картинка, а не какая-то ерунда? 

Знаю про .error(), но ведь оно тут не пойдёт, ибо надо сначала проверить, а потом уже пихать в превью.)